# Cannot read property of 'navigate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to make a stack navigator using reactstack navigation. When the button clicks, it appears on the detail screen only, the title of the page is detail. I am not yet to parsing data array to the next screen, it just tries to navigate the screen into the detail screen, and gets this error. I am new to react. Please help me solve this problem.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Button, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Text, View} from 'react-native'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


const Item = ({id, user_id, title, onPress, navigation}) => {
  
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Id :{id}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>User Id :{user_id}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Tittle :{title}
            </Text>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detail')} title='Detail'></Button>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.line}></View>
        </View>
    )

}


const Berita = () => {
    const [users,
        setUsers] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    const selectItem = (item) => {
        console.log('Selected item: ', item)
    }

    const getData = () => {
        axios
            .get('https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/posts')
            .then(res => {
                console.log('res: ', res);
                setUsers(res.data.data);
            })
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            {users.map(user => {
                return <Item key={user.id} id={user.id} user_id={user.user_id} title={user.title}/>
            })}
        </ScrollView>

    )
}

export default Berita

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 15
    },
    text: {
        color: "black",
        marginTop: 5,
        fontStyle: 'italic',
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: 'Arial'
    },
    line: {
        height: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        marginVertical: 20
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 25,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: "black"
    },
    tombol: {
        padding: 10
    }

})
```

This is the stack screen navigator code

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const DetailBerita = () => {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator >
            <Stack.Screen
                name='Berita'
                component={Berita}
                options={{
                headerTitleAlign: 'center'
            }}/>
            <Stack.Screen
                name="Detail"
                component={Detail}
                options={{
                headerTitleAlign: 'center'
            }}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using Stack Navigators with different screen names, but you didn't send it. If possible, can you send that file, I would be able to help you a bit better. But from what I have I can try and explain how Stack navigation works. With this line of code:

```
navigation.navigate('Detail')
```

You specify that you want to navigate to the screen named "Detail", if you want to navigate to another screen then you can change it to the name of the screen. Let's say you want to navigate to your home screen, and its named "Home" in your Stack.Navigation component. Simply change your navigation to the following:

```
navigation.navigate('Home')
```

Comment: hey, ive just edit my post and send you some file..

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `navigation` prop is passed to the `Berita` component and you are destructuring the property in `Item` component not in `Berita`.

So the code should look like

```
...
const Berita = ({ navigation }) => {

// ... 

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      {users.map(user => {
        return (
          <Item
            key={user.id}
            id={user.id}
            user_id={user.user_id}
            title={user.title}
            navigation={navigation} // Pass navigation
          />
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Another way is - you can just use navigation in `onPress` (Berita) and pass down `onPress` to `Item` component

```
const Item = ({ id, user_id, title, onPress }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Id :{id}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>User Id :{user_id}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Tittle :{title}</Text>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button onPress={onPress} title="Detail" />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.line}></View>
    </View>
  );
};

const Berita = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const selectItem = item => {
    console.log('Selected item: ', item);
  };

  const getData = () => {
    axios.get('https://gorest.co.in/public/v1/posts').then(res => {
      console.log('res: ', res);
      setUsers(res.data.data);
    });
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
      {users.map(user => {
        return (
          <Item
            key={user.id}
            id={user.id}
            user_id={user.user_id}
            title={user.title}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detail')}
          />
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Comment: very helpfull, thanks man

Comment: i try the second one, and the result is , its doing nothing bro,. the button is not working

Comment: Ok , let me try myself and I will update answer

Comment: @AgusRyan, here is an working example : https://snack.expo.dev/@arnabxd/e850bf

Comment: bro, if the return is the <flatlist>, how i can call the onPress ? , i use flatlist beacuse i make the pagination data , this is my flatlist ` <FlatList
        data={users}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detail')}
        ListFooterComponent={renderLoader}
        onEndReached={loadMoreItem}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}/>`

Comment: you need to use `onPress` in `renderItem` component. Please don't extend this question. Also if your primary problem (this particular question) is solved you can mark this as answer.

Comment: ok thanks bro. it meeans so much to me.. Thank for the help man